# density for Gaussian gram matrices

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability

Let $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma \otimes I)$ (so the columns of $Z$ are distributed $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$) and $A = Z'Z.$ Is there a name for the distribution on $A$? Is the density known?

Comment: If $Z'$ means the transpose, isn't this the Wishart distribution/density?

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread. So the columns are iid but the rows need not be?

Comment: Isn't this related to the: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. So is $Z$ a row vector of i.i.d. normals with mean zero and prescribed variance?

Comment: $Z$ is a matrix whose columns are distributed $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma).$ If the rows were distributed that way, then $Z'Z$ would be a Wishart distribution.

Comment: I am also interested in this question.  Have you made any progress?